# Pymongo, orden de grabacion de datos en mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

Estoy usando el modulo pymongo, para grabar datos en una colección de mongodb. Pero, cuando voy a revisar los datos, me encuentro que no se graban en el orden en el cual los he escrito. Si los inserto directamente desde el shell de mongodb, no hay problemas. He leido que por defecto tanto insert_one e insert_many, graban los datos en el mismo orden que se escribe, ¿pero no se donde esta el problema?. Estoy usando la ultima version del modulo 3.4.0 y la versión de mongo 2.6.11 (la que tiene el repositorio de ubuntu).

mi codigo

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

serverdb = MongoClient('10.10.10.10', 27017)
db = serverdb.ERP
coleccion = db.FichaCliente
coleccion.insert_one({'1 nombre':'Antonio', '2 telefono':999999999, '3 email':'email@email.email'})
serverdb.close()
```

¿Alguna idea del porque?

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres mantener un orden concreto debes utilizar un contenedor que preserve el orden, `dict` no lo hace.

En la librería estándar existe un contenedor `OrderedDict` que sí lo mantiene.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

...
datos = {'1 nombre':'Antonio', '2 telefono':999999999, '3 email':'email@email.email'}
coleccion.insert_one(OrderedDict(sorted(datos.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

En este ejemplo ordenaría los datos en función de la clave de cada elemento del diccionario.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Nuno André